# Docker volume with restart always option enabled

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, mounted-volumes

I have problem to configure my docker-compose file that docker can restart containers on reboot(my OS is Ubuntu 16.04). The problem isn't when I pass `restart: always` into it, but when my container need some volume-based file (e.g. ssl-cert into nginx). My code(in docker-compose.yml):

```
php:
    entrypoint: ["wait-for-it", "dockerhost:3306", "-t", "0", "--", "/install.sh"]
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=prod
    volumes:
      - ${FILE}:/file
      - /code
    env_file:
      - prod.env
    restart: always
```

And everything is ok when I start it by myself. Then I'm checking it if it will work after reboot. But nah, it don't work, `docker-compose ps` gives:

```
Name                    Command                State      Ports   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------          
panel_php_1        wait-for-it dockerhost:330 ...   Exit 127
```

By executing `docker inspect panel_php_1` it echoes error:

```
"Error": "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:359: container init caused \\\"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\\\\\"/home/mblocinski/hehe.txt\\\\\\\" to rootfs \\\\\\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/d746adf311098a9e2ffc27d9447a3e448ecfb9081ff4757704c24ec51ef9053e\\\\\\\" at \\\\\\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/d746adf311098a9e2ffc27d9447a3e448ecfb9081ff4757704c24ec51ef9053e/file\\\\\\\" caused \\\\\\\"not a directory\\\\\\\"\\\"\"\n: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type"
```

And Mounts:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/mblocinski/hehe.txt",
                "Destination": "/file",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
]
```

I'm sure that hehe.txt file is an file, not directory. Maybe it will be helpful if I say that mounting volume into container that is directory works well. Please help, searched already whole internet and nothing really works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if /home is encrypted by encfs. By default Ubuntu configures this feature during installation.

Run this command: `mount|grep home` and check if output has `type encfs` or something like.

Comment: Yes indeed it has `type ecryptfs` when I changed file source to /etc/file everything works